# Clean Windows install on Lenovo M720q with M.2 drive

Tags: windows, pci-express, intel-rst

I was playing around with the computer mentioned in the topic. The play ended up with wiped hard drive. I used to have there VMWare ESX installed. Now I wish I return to Windows.

I have downloaded Win 10 64-bit installation ISO. I have created bootable USB with diskutil tool on Mac. The computer is booting from this USB drive.

The question appeared to install the drivers for hard drive. So I have downloaded the RST driver from Lenovo support site. I have extracted the EXE file with Wine and copied the driver files to other USB.

I have returned to installation and connected the second USB drive to other port. I was able to select the directory with drivers and after a while the appropriate drivers appeared on the list. However the window popped up that there is no proper driver for the device and I should check if there is proper one on the USB.

I am stuck here. Could someone help, please?

Comment: Have you disabled Intel RST within the firmware and made sure UEFI only mode is enabled.  This means making sure Legacy Mode/CSM is disabled.

Comment: I was playing around with SATA as AHCI and SATA as RST. Yet I had the UEFI set to Auto. I was starting the USB as UEFI.

Comment: You want to use AHCI.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help at all. The drive still requires drivers during windows installation. I also tried to format the drive with GPT partition and added there one NTFS. No luck (yet linux has no issues with the drive at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Lenovo M70s with M.2 Drive.

I replaced the drive with a bigger SSD drive, so fresh install.

I ordered the Lenovo Recovery USB Drive.  2 days order to receipt.

I started with the USB in the USB Drive.  Press F12 repeatedly and then (20 seconds later) the Lenovo Recovery started running.

I tried with the Windows USB but that did not work (drivers I expect).

The Lenovo Recovery USB works great. The machine is running fine (and upgraded to Windows 11 on the way by).

The value of this approach is that all Lenovo Drivers as well as Windows will be loaded.

Comment: I wish I could use this solution. Lenovo has some maintenance for two days and I cannot download the recovery using their recovery tool (DDRS).

Comment: Stay with them and contact Lenovo Support (phone 1-855 253-6686) for help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think I could call them in the morning on their Polish number. For now I sent them a form message.

Comment: I was able to download the Recovery and made the USB key. The computer boots from this yet with error: Unexpected error. Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Well no. I can't. It does not work. There is error on blue screen on boot.

Comment: Shut down, insert the USB key, start up, press F12 right away and repeatedly so as to get the boot menu. Start with the USB key and the you should see the recovery screen and should be able to proceed. That does not depend upon the state of the existing OS on the drive. Make sure you have a good Recovery USB Key

Comment: So it seems some corruption is on USB or downloaded image. This error appears on booting from USB. When I boot linux USB all is fine. I'll try redoing the USB key.

Comment: Yes! Redoing the key did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the update. My own Key and fresh install went perfectly well.